# If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M$, show that there exists a number $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow |g(x)| < 1 + |M|.$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, definition

The hint given was to take $\epsilon = 1$ for the formal definition of a limit. Doing this means that $|g(x) - M| < 1.$ Using the triangle inequality, you get $$|g(x)| = |(g(x) - M) + M| \le |g(x) - M| + |M| < 1 + |M|.$$
It also appears that the same method can be applied for $0 <\,\epsilon < 1.$

For $\epsilon = 0.5$, you end up getting $|g(x)| < 0.5 + |M| < 1 + |M|.$

How can the question be answered for $\epsilon > 1$?

Comment: Can you provide the formal definition of a limit you operate with? Your question seems to be some form of misunderstanding, usual definition doesn't specify some $\epsilon$ but states something about *every* $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why $\varepsilon>1$ ? You just want a neighborhood of $a$ s.t. $|g(x)|<1+|M|$. This is obviously not true for all $x\in \mathbb R$ !

Comment: @Abstraction $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$, if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

Comment: @Surb Is $|g(x)| < 1 + |M|$ in a way saying that $g(x)$ is between $M \pm 1$? If so, then I'd see why $0 < \epsilon < 1$. But there's also the absolute value of M.

Comment: @IvanQuartey Then, as you see, the question doesn't include any particular $\epsilon$ value. Statement "$\exists \delta : x \in O_\delta(a) \implies g(x) \in O_\epsilon(M)$" (or shorter, $\exists \delta : g(O_\delta(a)) \subseteq O_\epsilon(M)$) is true for any $\epsilon$ - for example, for $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: @Abstraction Could you give a comment that's less symbolic? I haven't learnt Maths at University yet.

Comment: @IvanQuartey The statement "$g(x)$ has a limit $M$ at $x \to a$" means that for **any** neighbourhood of $M$ (having "width" $\epsilon$), there is (exists) a "punctured" neighbourhood of $a$ (having "width" $\delta$) so that $g$ maps every element of the latter into the former. You're asked to prove that there is some punctured neighbourhood of $a$ which $g$ maps inside $(-1-|M|,1+|M|)$. To do that, you take a $\delta$-neighbourhood such that $g$ maps it inside 1-neighbourhood of $M$ (definition of limit tells you it exists) and then show that $(M-1,M+1)$ lies inside $(-1-|M|,1+|M|)$.

Comment: @Abstraction Wouldn't this mean that $\epsilon$ is restricted, since if you can only map a $\delta$-neighbourhood to an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood with $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Comment: @IvanQuartey No and I don't see how you get that restriction. Statement which is definition of limit holds for any $\epsilon>0$ (and by the way, if you have $\delta$-neighbourhood of $a$ which is mapped inside $1$-neighbourhood of $M$, then it is also mapped inside any bigger neighbourhood, isn't it?). You use this given fact to prove some (much weaker) statement, for that out of all possible values of $\epsilon$ you choose one particular case, $\epsilon = 1$ and take one particular punctured neighbourhood.

Comment: @Abstraction If we say $g(x)$ lies in the open interval $(M - \epsilon, M + \epsilon)$, it $doesn't$ mean that $g(x)$ must take every value between $M - \epsilon$ and $M + \epsilon$? If so, then I understand what you're saying. So then $|g(x)| < 2 + |M| \Rightarrow |g(x)| < 1 +|M|$, since $(-1 - |M|, 1 + |M|)$ lies in $(-2 -|M|, 2 + |M|)$

Comment: @IvanQuartey No, it doesn't. Clear example - $\exists \lim_{x \to 0}x^2 = 0$, note that $x^2$ is never negative, yet all neighbourhoods of $0$ contain negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already solved your question when you finish the use of triangle inequality. Why do you want to go for other values of $\epsilon$'s? The question is clearly not talking about any $\epsilon$. It is just asking you to find a $\delta > 0$ such that some specific statement containing $\delta$ is true. You have already shown that such a $\delta$ is there.

There is no need to think of anything further. Perhaps you have some misunderstanding of the definition of limit.

The definition of $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ says that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that the inequality $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ holds for all $x$ with $0 < |x - a| < \delta$.

The meaning of the above definition is somewhat difficult to grasp initially because the definition guarantees the truth of an infinite number of statements (one statement namely $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for each $\epsilon > 0$). Also the truth of each such statement is not for all $x$ but for some specific values of $x$ based on $\epsilon$. This is where $\delta$ comes into picture. The definition thus says that for each $\epsilon$ the statement $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ is true provided we restrict $x$ to $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ for some specific number $\delta$ based on $\epsilon$. Thus the meaning of limit is very strong.

On the other hand your question gives you that $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = M$. This means that each statement of type $|g(x) - M| < \epsilon$ is true for specific values of $x$ depending on $\epsilon$. Your question asks us to show the truth of *just one* of these statements. The *student has to guess* that the question is asking for the truth of the specific statement for $\epsilon = 1$. That's all the question is asking. It is not asking about the statements related to other values of $\epsilon$ (although by definition of limit they are also guaranteed to be true for specific values of $x$).